# Reducing table height in html/php

Tags: php, html, html-table

I am working plotting one html/php table using following code.

```
$color=array("#000000","#0000FF","00FFFF","#00FF00","#FFFF00","#7FFFD4","#FF0000","#FF9900","#FFFFFF","#00BFFF");
echo "<br>Color Codes:<br><br>";
echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>';

     for($i=0;$i< sizeof($color); $i++)
     {
        echo "<td height='5px' width='10' bgcolor='".$color[$i]."'>($i/10)</td>";
     }
 echo  '</tr>';
 echo  '</table><br>';
```

But when I plot this I get following output:

[image]

Here height does not decrease with height paramer as I need to just create rectangular boxes.

Comment: You are not trying to set a variable height and anyway you can't have a table row with different height cells

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your code and didn't see what you're seeing, so I think you may have other styles on the page where you're plotting this that are interfering with the layout. You can take the `height` attribute off the `td` elements; then try adding a `style=""` attribute on the `table` and testing different properties.

`<table style="line-height: 1;">` - try that for starters.